# SSIS: Acquiring name for prior data flow component

Tags: input, path, ssis, custom-component

I'm trying to enhance my error logging in SSIS. In addition to using SSIS's built in logging (OnError, OnWarning, etc.) which gets saved to sysssislog, I also keep track of specific rows that get redirected to error outputs (I convert the rows to xml, add the name of the package and data flow task, and drop the rows into a table in the database). I'm trying to enhance the information captured when tracking redirected error rows by also including which data flow component threw the error.

My problem is that I can't figure out how best to pass on the component name so it becomes part of the workflow. The first thought I had was to create a custom component that would capture this information, but I can't seem to find a way to backtrack from an IDTSInput100 object back to its associated IDTSPath100 object. If I could do that, then I think I could get the ID of the IDTSOutput100 object associated with it and then go one step back further so I could get the metadata from the prior component in the data flow.

Any advice on how best to accomplish my ultimate goal? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to get the upstream component name! I used the GetVirtualInput method for each IDTSInput100 object and then accessed the IDTSVirtualInputColumn100 objects to find the UpstreamComponentName. There has got to be an easier way, but at least I was able to do what I needed.

Also rvphx, thanks for the suggestion. That'll be useful for getting the name and description of the error column.

Answer (score 1):

Not reading too much into this, but cant you just have a derived column and add all the information you want to the outgoing error rows? I generally add the custom error messages this way (on Lookups) saying that "Failed Lookup for Customer  ID: [ColumnName]". This works good for me.

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify what you mean? When you perform a Lookup, you connect the error output to a Derived Column component that adds a column saying "Failed Lookup for __________" before dumping the error row in a table? If so, that's not quite what I'm looking for. I want to build something that will streamline the process and take away as much manual work as possible from setting up error logging in projects. The hope is to automatically get the name of the component that redirected the error row so no additional manual work required besides connecting the error output.

Comment: Here is something that can help you. But its not straight forward. http://bennyaustin.wordpress.com/2011/02/04/ssis-name-of-errorcolumn/ Let us know if this is of any use.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it using (user1956536) comment above. Agreed this is nasty and there has to be a better way of doing it.

```
    IDTSInputCollection100 inputCollection = ComponentMetaData.InputCollection;
    String upStreamComponent = String.Empty;
    if(inputCollection.Count > 0)
    {
        IDTSVirtualInput100 virtualInput =  inputCollection[0].GetVirtualInput();
        IDTSVirtualInputColumnCollection100 virtualInputColumnCollection = virtualInput.VirtualInputColumnCollection;
        if (virtualInputColumnCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            upStreamComponent = virtualInputColumnCollection[0].UpstreamComponentName;
        }
    }

    Row.ErrorDescription = ComponentMetaData.GetErrorDescription(Row.ErrorCode);
    Row.ErrorComponent = upStreamComponent;
```